Regularization of Interest Rate Inverse Problem failing
I'm going through this Inverse Problems textbook: https://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/invprobs/inversefin1.pdf . In one exercise, I have to perform a regularization on an inverse problem, but I get results even worse than the non-regularized problem, and I've found no value of $\alpha$ which produces a better fit than the non-regularized solution - so I'm pretty sure I've made a mistake.
The regularization method I'm implementing is on page 28 of the textbook.
We have the regularization matrix $\textbf{A}$, the forward-difference-calculated-derivative $\textbf{b}$, and we solve for $\textbf{d}$ - the regularized derivatives.
$$\textbf{Ad}=\textbf{b}$$
$$
\textbf{A} = \textbf{I} + \frac{\alpha}{\Delta t^2} \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & -1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 2 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$\mathbf{A}$ is an MxM matrix, where M = number_of_data_points - 1
$$\mathbf{b} = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{f_1 - f_0}{\Delta t} \\
\frac{f_2 - f_1}{\Delta t} \\
\frac{f_3 - f_2}{\Delta t} \\
\vdots \\
\frac{f_{M-1} - f_{M-2}}{\Delta t} \\
\frac{f_M - f_{M-1}}{\Delta t}
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{d} = \begin{pmatrix}
d_0 \\
d_1 \\
d_2 \\
\vdots \\
d_{M-1} \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
I'm applying this method to problem 12 - b, page 32: We want to recover the interest rate from a sequence of balance-data, subjected to a round-off error.
Here are 2 screenshots of the result: https://imgur.com/a/85L4CUT . You can see the unregularized-R wobble around the true R, but it's still far better than the regularized R, which shouldn't be happening. What am I getting wrong?
Here is my Python code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dt = 1/365
alpha = 0.01

# The initial amount P(0)
P0 = 100


def calculateRAtT(t: float):
    return 0.1*(2+np.sin(t))


def calculateRsAtT(t_values):
    return 0.1*(2+np.sin(t_values))


def P_single(t):
    # Numerical integration of r(t) from 0 to t using the trapezoidal rule

    # Generate 1000 points for a smooth integral
    t_values = np.linspace(0, t, 1000)

    r_values = calculateRsAtT(t_values)

    integral = np.trapz(r_values, t_values)
    # Calculate the final amount P(t) using the formula P(0) * exp(integral of r(t) dt)
    P_t = P0 * np.exp(integral)

    return P_t


def getNaiveDerivativeOfP(P):
    return np.diff(P)/dt


def getRegularizationMatrix(P):
    M = len(P)-1
    offDiagonal = -np.ones(M-1)
    mainDiagonal = 2*np.ones(M)
    mainDiagonal[0] = 1
    mainDiagonal[-1] = 1
    ATridiagonal = np.diag(mainDiagonal) + \
        np.diag(offDiagonal, 1) + np.diag(offDiagonal, -1)
    regularization_matrix = 1+(alpha/(dt**2)) * ATridiagonal

    return regularization_matrix


def getRegularizedDerivativeOfP(P):
    regularizationMatrix = getRegularizationMatrix(P)
    naiveDerivative = getNaiveDerivativeOfP(P)
    solution = np.linalg.solve(regularizationMatrix, naiveDerivative)
    return solution


def calculateNaiveR(P):
    return getNaiveDerivativeOfP(P)/P[:-1]


def calculateRegularizedR(P):
    return getRegularizedDerivativeOfP(P)/P[:-1]


trueR = []
continuousRt = np.arange(0, 5, dt)
for t in continuousRt:
    trueR.append(calculateRAtT(t))

continuousP = []
for t in continuousRt:
    # Here we round, introducing an error which we want to overcome using regularization
    PAtT = round(P_single(t), 2)
    continuousP.append(PAtT)

calculatedNaiveR = calculateNaiveR(continuousP)
calculatedRegularizedR = calculateRegularizedR(continuousP)

plt.plot(continuousRt, trueR, label="true R")
plt.plot(continuousRt[:-1], calculatedNaiveR, label="calculated naive R")
plt.plot(continuousRt[:-1], calculatedRegularizedR, label="calculated regularized R")
plt.title('Array Plot')
plt.xlabel('Index')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


use np.eye(M) for the identity matrix.
def getRegularizationMatrix(P):
    M = len(P)-1
    offDiagonal = -np.ones(M-1)
    mainDiagonal = 2*np.ones(M)
    mainDiagonal[0] = 1
    mainDiagonal[-1] = 1
    ATridiagonal = np.diag(mainDiagonal) + \
        np.diag(offDiagonal, 1) + np.diag(offDiagonal, -1)
    regularization_matrix = np.eye(M)+(alpha/(dt**2)) * ATridiagonal

    return regularization_matrix

